# Why do I get a null reference exception when using FindAsync in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Using .NET Core 3.1 I have a simple controller method defined as follows:

```cs
[HttpGet( "{id}" )]
public async Task<ActionResult<Animal>> Get( [FromRoute] int id )
{
    var animal = await _dbContext.Animal.FindAsync( id );
    if( animal == null ) return NotFound();
    return Ok( animal );
}
```

When called with a valid id, this throws a null reference exception from within FindAsync.

If I convert to a synchronous method, and use Find instead, it works as expected.

I've tried changing Task to ValueTask, or adding .AsTask() to .FindAsync(), but it makes no difference.
How can I get an asynchronous call to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this syntax

`var animal = await _dbContext.Animal.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);`